# Virtual Routing for root virtual machines on 1 IP

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I wan't to install several (around 10) virtual machines on our server. We have 1 public IP-address assigned to it. I wan't to use virtualbox (and phpvirtualbox for administration).
I have no control over the routing environment from our Service Provider.

What is the best strategy for virtual routing. Ideally I wan't to distinguish the single VM with a domain name and not use port forwarding. Is there a way to do this without extra hardware. I understand I can use a web proxy for http redirecting and port forwarding for ssh access, but what if we need i.e mail (on standard port) for several machines.

Answer (score 0):

Outgoing you can use NAT for all machines, no problem. Incoming however is going to be a challenge. for some traffic you can use nginx as a reverse proxy (lots of docs on that subject on the web), in the case of mail you can use a email forwarder that listens on port 25 on the outside, and sends it to the right server based on recipient. Otherwise if its only 1 email server, point the port directly to that machine.

SSH is going to be a challenge. However a possible solution for that is (management) set up a VPN gateway, which allows you to VPN in and manage the machines on their local IP's The VPN gateway can be set up as a virtual machine aswell in the form of a linux or bsd router (examples are: monowall, ipcop or pfsense)